# Appending to a tuple overwriting previous values

Tags: python, append, tuples, arcpy

I'm using arcpy to get all the polylines of a shape file. `SearchCursor` returns a cursor so that I can iterate over all the features of shape file. Problem is I want to save all the objects returned by cursor for later use.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\GIS Data\GIS data"

desc = arcpy.Describe("River.shp")
shapefieldname = desc.ShapeFieldName

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("River.shp")

featureList = ()

for row in rows:
    feat = row.getValue(shapefieldname)

    featureList = featureList + (feat, )

    print "%i %i" % (featureList[-1].firstPoint.X, featureList[-1].firstPoint.Y)
    print "%i %i" % (featureList[-1].lastPoint.X, featureList[-1].lastPoint.Y)

    print

print "---------------------------------------------------------------"

for feat in featureList:
    print "%i %i" % (feat.firstPoint.X, feat.firstPoint.Y)
    print "%i %i" % (feat.lastPoint.X, feat.lastPoint.Y)
    print
```

Tuple supposed to contain all the objects returned by cursor. But it has only the last elements repeated `size` of tuple number of times.

> 3610930 2135882 3611593 2134453
>
> 3611806 2134981 3611593 2134453
>
> 3614160 2136164 3617432 2131734
>
> 3611593 2134453 3617432 2131734
>
> 3617432 2131734 3620568 2127591
>
> 3620568 2127591 3620785 2127423
>
> 3617980 2126657 3620568 2127591
>
> 3616768 2129454 3617948 2126649
>
> 3617948 2126649 3617980 2126657
>
> 3615102 2128889 3617587 2126510
>
> 3617587 2126510 3617948 2126649
>
> 3617624 2126416 3617980 2126657
>
> 3613129 2128176 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615155 2125617 3617587 2126510
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> ---
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617

At first, I've tried this using list. Same output was also found for list when I've used 'append()' method. As tuple is immutable data structure, how can `+` overwrites all the previous elements of tuple. Although this code is written for arcpy, but I guess the problem isn't arcgis specific.

Comment: The problem is most likely in your `row.getValue(shapefieldname)` call, check what it is returning -- it is not in how your using tuples (or lists). The latter would be more efficient for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this suggests is that `row.getValue()` keeps returning references *to the same object*, which it keeps updating in place.

To verify, try printing `id(feat)`, `id(feat.firstPoint)` and `id(feat.lastPoint)` in the first loop, and see whether any of the ids remain the same between iterations. If any of them do, that's your problem.

> As tuple is immutable data structure, how can + overwrites all the previous elements of tuple.

It doesn't. Tuple is immutable in the sense that you can't add or remove elements from it without creating a new tuple. You also can't change the value of a tuple element. However, if that element is a reference to a mutable object, you are free to modify the object itself. This is what I suspect is happening here: you have multiple references to the same object; when you modify one, they all appear to change.

Comment: No, that's not the case. `row.getValue()` returns difference objects. See the 1st group outputs, it's printing difference values for the last object of tuple `print "%i %i" % (featureList[-1].firstPoint.X, featureList[-1].firstPoint.Y)`.

Comment: @crucifiedsoul: Please humour me and print out `id(feat)`.

Comment: @crucifiedsoul: While we are at it, also please print out `id(feat.firstPoint)` and `id(feat.lastPoint)`.

Comment: @crucified soul: In the first loop each time round the reference is set to a new object, but the list of references are all the same so e.g. if you replaced instances of featureList[-1] with featureList[0] you would also still get the same output.

Comment: @Simon Hibbs: How do you explain the fact that the first 15 values iterated over are different?

Comment: @aix: Yes, arcpy is showing strange behavior. It's somehow holding references to objects returned by cursor and changing it later.

Comment: No, it's not an arcpy problem. It's exactly as NPE explained. And "why are the first values different?": Because on the first loop, they got printed before they changed, but with each step on the loop all references to 'feat' in the tuple do change.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as a one line list comprehension:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\GIS Data\GIS data"

desc = arcpy.Describe("River.shp")
shapefieldname = desc.ShapeFieldName

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("River.shp")

feature_list = [row.getValue( shapefieldname ) for row in rows]
```

In this example 'feature_list' will be a list of the value of your shape field.