# Loading a feature class in a list using arcpy : strange behaviour of SearchCursor

Tags: python, geometry, arcpy

Using `arcpy`, my purpose is to stock a feature class in a list for further processing.
Each row will be a dict of `{'field name': value}`, including geometry.

The most pythonic way to achieve this task should be to use list comprehension :

```
fc = '/path/to/fc'
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]   # get field list
features = [[row.getValue(f) for f in fields] for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)]
```

This method works for data but geometries in the list are all the same (the last geometry retrieved in fc). [This behaviour of SearchCursor has already been commented on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815149/appending-to-a-tuple-overwriting-previous-values).

I tried another approach:

```
fc = '/path/to/fc'
shape_field = arcpy.Describe(fc).shapeFieldName

# load geometry in a list
geom = arcpy.Geometry()
feat = [{shape_field: f} for f in arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, geom)] # slow

# load data in a list
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
data = [dict([(f, row.getValue(f)) for f in fields if f != shape_field]) for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)] # slow

# merge
merge = zip(feat, data)
merge = [dict([(k, v) for adict in line for (k, v) in adict.items()]) for line in merge] # sorry for that...
```

It works with my dataset but:

- It is slow.
- I'm not sure it's safe to assert that data and feat come in the same order.

Any opinion on that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If at all possible, migrate to using 10.1 where you get `arcpy.da`, a significantly more performant API for cursors. [I've written a log post on this very topic of getting dictionaries back](http://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/getting-arcpy-da-rows-back-as-dictionaries/). Geometries will all be the same because it uses a recycling cursor internally, so in 10.0 you'll want to grab `shape.__geo_interface__` instead and use `AsShape` to get it back to a geometry object.

The order you get rows back is fairly arbitrary: you can expect it to be the same every time in a shapefile *without* a where clause and that's pretty much it, so your two-pass approach won't really be reliable.

All this considered, you can do something like this:

```
def cursor_to_dicts(cursor, field_names):
    for row in cursor:
        row_dict = {}
        for field in field_names:
            val = row.getValue(field)
            row_dict[field] = getattr(val, '__geo_interface__', val)
        yield row_dict

fc = '/path/to/fc'
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]   # get field list
features = list(cursor_to_dicts(arcpy.SearchCursor(fc), fields))
```

The magic is the `getattr()` call -- try to grab `value.__geo_interface__` if it exists, otherwise just default to `value`.

As this question isn't really about the Python language in general but an API (`arcpy`) specific to GIS, you might be better off asking things like this on gis.stackexchange in the future.

Comment: I wasn't aware of arcpy.da which seems to be a great improvement for data access : http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000. Having upgraded to 10.3 i'm going to give it a try. Thank you for this great tip @JasonShierer

Comment: ...and another option would be to use arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray : http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000015000000

Comment: ...last edit : i have sp3 installed but being in France 10.1 is not available yet for me. I'll have to go for `__geo_interface__`.